# WebForms - Response.Redirect() does not change URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I do have a big problem and can't find any solution.

I have three .aspx pages. 
1) Login
2) Menu
3) Days

Login page has a Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="bt_login" onClick="bt_login_Click" runat="server" Text="Login" />
```

and this method:

```
protected void bt_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Menu.aspx");        
}
```

When I click the Button it redirects to Menu.aspx but the URL still says Login.aspx
So when I click any Button in Menu.aspx it will direct me back to Login.aspx

When I tried to put the Redirect into the Page_Load method it worked, why?

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: no I don't.. <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Menu.aspx" Text="go"/>  would work at the same position as the asp:Button

Comment: Are you using any update panel, or any AJAX related stuff. I guess thats the culprit.

Comment: I'm using jQuery Mobile in combination..

Comment: Yeah, it works without the jquery scripts :(

Comment: Does the page post back when you click the button? Are there any jquery items/events tied to the your bt_login button? As the person said above, this sounds like some client side script might be interfering.

Comment: What do you mean with "post back"? I use jQuery only for design, so yes the button looks like a jQuery button.. I outcommented eveything on the page and only left the Button but it still didn't work, so I outcommented the sources for the jquery scripts and it worked.. but I need them!

Comment: Sounds like your jQuery is intercepting the click and not actually letting it happen.

Comment: sigh. Does anyone know how I can handle that? I have absolutely no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

Your are likely using authentication of some sorts (Windows/Forms/etc) and and you are not logged in.  Check your web.config, as it probably has a redirect to the login page until you are logged in. The menu.aspx page is not allowed unless you are logged in, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I use jquery mobile.

```
        If FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(strUsername, strPassword) Then
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(strUsername, False)
        Else
            ' show login error
            lblLoginError.Visible = True
        End If
```

It takes me to the default.aspx page after I authenticate, but the url of the page has a return url listed and the css not working correctly.

I commented this out (below) and it works:

```
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```